# I am getting this in sfmc Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax

Tags: sql

i am getting below error in sql.

```
Select Journey_Duration,
CASE
WHEN (Journey_Duration='CompleteYourQuote') THEN
(Select (C.Count+E.Count) as Conversion, 1 as Flag
FROM (Select COUNT(A.EmailAddress) as Count,'J' as JoinCriteria
FROM TEST_Three_Complete_Quote2_Archive_20190918 A
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Contact_20190201 B ON A.EmailAddress=B.EmailAddress
Where A.Emailaddress in (Select Emailaddress From TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190910)
OR A.Emailaddress in (Select Emailaddress From TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190311)) C
INNER JOIN
(Select COUNT(D.EmailAddress) as Count,'J' as JoinCriteria
FROM TEST_Three_Complete_Quote_Archive_20190307 D
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Contact_20190201 B ON D.EmailAddress=B.EmailAddress
WHERE D.Emailaddress in (Select Emailaddress From TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190910)
OR D.Emailaddress in (Select Emailaddress From TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190311)) E
ON C.JoinCriteria= E.JoinCriteria)
END AS CompleteYourQuote,
CASE
WHEN (Journey_Duration='PurchaseYourPolicy') THEN
(Select (G.Count+L.Count) as Conversion, 1 as Flag
FROM (Select COUNT(T.EmailAddress) as Count,'J' as JoinCriteria FROM TEST_Three_Contact_20190201 B
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190910 T ON B.EmailAddress=T.EmailAddress
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Policy_20190201 F ON T.QuoteNumber = F.QuoteNumber     where B.PartyID is not null) 
 G
INNER JOIN
(Select COUNT(H.EmailAddress) as Count,'J' as JoinCriteria
FROM TEST_Three_Contact_20190201 B
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Purchase_Policy_Archive_20190311 H ON B.EmailAddress=H.EmailAddress
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Policy_20190201 F ON H.QuoteNumber=F.QuoteNumber where B.PartyID is not null) L
ON G.JoinCriteria= L.JoinCriteria)
END AS PurchaseYourPolicy,
CASE
WHEN (Journey_Duration='StartYourQuote') THEN
(Select COUNT(M.EmailAddress) as Conversion,1 as Flag
from TEST_Three_StartYourQuote_Archive_20190412 M
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Contact_20190201 B ON M.EmailAddress=B.EmailAddress
INNER JOIN TEST_Three_Quote_20190201 N ON B.PartyID = N.PartyID Where N.QuoteNumber is not null)
END AS StartYourQuote
from
TEST_Three_Conversion_20200611
```

Comment: The syntax is ANSI SQL compliant. Core SQL-99, plus derived tables.

Comment: Which dbms is it that complains?